# Check when multiple asynchronous network operations are completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, asynchronous, afnetworking

My app downloads lots of info and images from users on Flickr, and I use AFHttpClient. So basically, everyone goes through what is effectively an `NSUrlConnection` asynchronously, and then a completion block runs. One class has methods for each api call, and another loops through the api calls to get each users data, which is put into core data. However, my problem is that I cannot figur out a way for the class calling the api class to determine when all the downloads are done and to put it in core data. Also, I will have multiple users data being downloaded simultaneously, and different attributes finish loading in different orders depending in the user. Any suggestions?

Comment: Were you able to find any solution? Please post some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a count of how many active requests are in progress using an instance variable. This could be a simple NSInteger which is incremented and decremented, or it could be a dictionary, keyed by the user name, and holding a number or more detailed tracking record if required. It really depends what level of detail you need. The class which makes the API calls should do all of the management of this record data and just offer 'count' methods.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking made it quite simple to manage multiple request and final callback, juste use :

```
- (void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:(NSArray *)operations 
                          progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock 
                        completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock;
```

or

```
- (void)enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperationsWithRequests:(NSArray *)urlRequests
                                      progressBlock:(void (^)(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations))progressBlock 
                                    completionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *operations))completionBlock;
```

on AFHHTPClient instance.

Exemple :

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
NSURLRequest *otherRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationForImages = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operationForImages setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //success of images request
    self.imageDictionary = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    //manage error for this request

}];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationForText = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:otherRequest];
[operationForText setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //success of text request
    self.textDictionary = responseObject;

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    //manage error for this request

}];


[[MyPersonalAFHTTPClient sharedClient] enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:@[operationForImages,operationForText] progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {

    //track progression of requests

} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {

    //all the request are completed

}];
```